# Laravel email sends only in debug mode

Tags: laravel, email, debugging

I hope someone can help me. Searched every combination for this issue.

I have an Laravel (5.4) app for invoicing. Its called Akaunting. App domain is **app.mydomain.com**

Everything works fine, except it doesn't sends email to customers when debug mode is off.
My .env file is setup properly.

Previousely I received maximum size exceeded, but only debug mode as well. Thats now sorted by increasing `upload_max_filesize = 254M` and `post_max_size = 254M`

I've tried `mail_driver=log` the email with success. First line `production.DEBUG: Message-ID: <3369a7418b3f17c887fd27888ebe9f12@app.mydomain.com>`

My .env looks like this and the emails are not send unless in debug mode:

```
APP_NAME=Akaunting
APP_ENV=production
APP_LOCALE=en-GB
APP_INSTALLED=true
APP_KEY=MySecureKey
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_SCHEDULE_TIME="09:00"

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql.host.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=akaunting_db
DB_USERNAME=akunting_usr
DB_PASSWORD=MyDbPassword
DB_PREFIX=gvf_

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file

# QUEUE_DRIVER=database
# QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=SMTP
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=GmailAppPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My App"
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@myapp.com
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Do you have anything in your application logs? (`/storage/logs/`). If the application is getting errors back from your Email provider they should be in there. It could be something simple like a throttle or an an authentication error

Comment: The file `/storage/logs/laravel.log` is empty after sending emails.In `debug=true` the email arrives immediately with PDF invoice attached.

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the gmail smtp settings

Comment: I double checked with own SMPT and the issue is the same.

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: Are you using queue jobs / notification to send email?

Comment: @DeepeshThapa not sure how to do/check both. I'm new to Laravel.

Comment: I cleared cache with

`Route::get('/clear-cache', function(){Artisan::call('cache:clear');return "Cache is cleared";});` in `/routes/web.php`

But still don't know how check queue jobs / notification.

Comment: Btw password reset email works fine.